# Not understanding how to use doesntHave in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Consider the following:

```
public function index() {
    return response()->json([
        'weapons'   => Item::doesntHave(['itemAffixes', 'artifactProperty'])->where('type', 'weapon')->all(),
        'armour'    => Item::doesntHave(['itemAffixes', 'artifactProperty'])->whereIn('type', [
            'body', 'leggings', 'sleeves', 'gloves', 'helmet', 'shield'
        ])->all(),

        'artifacts' => Item::where('type', 'artficat')->load('artifactProperty')->all(),
        'spells'    => Item::doesntHave(['itemAffixes', 'artifactProperty'])->where('type', 'spell')->all(),
        'rings'     => Item::doesntHave(['itemAffixes', 'artifactProperty'])->where('type', 'ring')->all(),
    ], 200);
}
```

When this action is hit by a test, I get: `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array` How do I do what I am attempting to do, but where it doesn't fail.

It should be clear what I am trying to do, but lets use `'weapon'` where it fails, as an example:

```
'weapons' => Item::doesntHave(['itemAffixes', 'artifactProperty'])->where('type', 'weapon')->all(),
```

Its suppose to do the query where: Get me all items where type is weapon and the item does not have a `artifactProperty` or `itemAffixes`

But I am unsure why I am getting this error. **Thoughts?**

Comment: `doesntHave()` might not accept an array as the input (the documentation/code suggests that it doesn't). Does it work if you chain them? `Item::doesntHave("itemAffixes")->doesntHave("artifactProperty")->where(...)->get();`?

Comment: I never knew it doesn't accept arrays, when `load` does ... let me check

Comment: Yeah, and a lot of Laravel methods are fluent in that if you pass multiple arguments vs an array of arguments then it "just works", so one accepting that and another not can be a little jarring. Also, `->load('artifactProperty')` in your query should be `->with('artifactProperty')`. `load()` is for after the model instance is loaded, `with()` is for eager loading before query finalization (performed by `all()` in this case)

Comment: and it would be `get` not `all` if you have the builder, `all` is actually a static method on Model

Comment: you should get familiar with reading the code of the framework so you can check the method signatures and see what the methods are doing with the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research and testing the following is the correct answer based on Tim Lewis's comments:

```
    return response()->json([
        'weapons'   => Item::doesntHave('itemAffixes')->doesntHave('artifactProperty')->where('type', 'weapon')->get(),
        'armour'    => Item::doesntHave('itemAffixes')->doesntHave('artifactProperty')->whereIn('type', [
            'body', 'leggings', 'sleeves', 'gloves', 'helmet', 'shield'
        ])->get(),

        'artifacts' => Item::with('artifactProperty')->where('type', 'artficat')->get(),
        'spells'    => Item::doesntHave('itemAffixes')->doesntHave('artifactProperty')->where('type', 'spell')->get(),
        'rings'     => Item::doesntHave('itemAffixes')->doesntHave('artifactProperty')->where('type', 'ring')->get(),
    ], 200);
```

- `doesntHave` does not allow you to pass an array, as stated above. Why? I have no idea, so chaining does work.
- `load` has to come after you fetched the collection
- `all` cannot be used, instead you "get" the collection. (all and get always trip me up)

*I did switch to `with` instead of `load`. Not sure what the performance benefits of this is, but it gives me the same json object regardless.*

Comment: People won't downvote for a self-answered question (at least they shouldn't), but the only correction I'd make is not using `->load()` at all, as you can do that using `->with()` (before `->get()`) and eager load directly from the database: `Item::where('type', 'artficat')->with('artifactProperty')->get();` (would be more efficient for large datasets)

Comment: @TimLewis Pretty sure both `with` and `load` does the same thing. They both retrieve the records first, then eager load the relationships.

Comment: @ChinLeung load is lazy eager loading ... with is eager loading ... can't call `with` after the fact, but you can `load` a relationship after the fact ... they would get the same records but they are done at different times

Comment: @lagbox Yes I know, but I mean in term of performance they should be the same. They both perform 1 extra query to retrieve the relationships after the parent records has been retrieved.

Comment: I've only ever used `load()` on a single Model instance that I didn't have the ability to directly query, so I gravitate towards `with()` in any case that I can. If they do the same thing, then it's irrelevant, but if `load()` is calling a new query for each instance, then it's definitely more efficient to use `with()`. All of this is just performance notes though; if the code works, then it works.

Comment: @TimLewis @lagbox Oops my bad, I thought we were comparing a single record situation. Didn't realize it was a collection. Yeah  I usually go with `with` as well too.

Comment: @ChinLeung Yeah, no worries. Either approach with regards to a single record hardly matters, but I'm unsure of the performance `load()` has when used with a `Collection` of model instances. That's why I suggested `with()` before `get()`, to allow the database to do the heavy lifting as opposed to PHP and `Collection` logic.

Comment: @ChinLeung seems they would be the same performance wise though

Comment: I did make a small change to my solution, `with` is used instead of `load`